# Sending JSON to WCF Rest Service - object fileds are null

Tags: javascript, wcf

I am using WCF Rest service with post method as below

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   UriTemplate = "/SampleMethod")]
    int SampleMethod(SampleObject sampleObject);
```

and called this service from Javascript as below,

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/SampleService/SampleService.svc/SampleMethod', 
        data: object,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json", 
        processdata: true, 
        success: successCallback, //On Successfull service call
        error: serviceFailed// When Service call fails
    });
```

Where object is is the strigified  json of the format

> {"sampleObject":{"ID":1, "Name":"ABC", "Data":"Sample data"}}

Above the sample of what I am trying to use, but on service side all object fields (ID, Name, Data) are null. I am not getting the problem.

Comment: When I've written that kind of code, I've never specified the `BodyStyle` and it works. Have you tried that? Otherwise, I'd have to see `SampleObject` to investigate further.

Comment: Can you add your endpoint configuration as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I found my mistake. There was a problem with data type mismatch. like int had a value blank string and also there was problem with date format.

Answer (score 3):

This is setting the properties as null because you are sending it, effectively, a "wrapped" object - the JSON you are sending it has an object with a property (sampleObject) which is another object which is your SampleObject.

You, therefore, have two options to how to solve this.

**Option 1**

You can set the request format to wrapped on the service, so just change your attribute on your operation contract to the following:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",    
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,    
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,    
           UriTemplate = "/SampleMethod")]
```

**Option 2**

Change your code that is stringifying the object such that it creates this JSON instead:

```
{"ID":1, "Name":"ABC", "Data":"Sample data"}
```

Since you are just sending a single argument I would, personally, go with option 2 as it saves you a bit of space on the wire.  I think you only really need the "wrapped" style if you want to send multiple arguments.